# My code is not executing when executed through command line where as running successfully from Eclipse

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, command, cucumber

I'm able to execute my Cucumber feature file from Eclipse but whereas same is not getting executed if I run through command prompt.

This is my code snippet:

Cucumber Feature File:

```
Given User Open Browser
```

The method where the browser is opening:

```
public static void open browser()  
{
    //Opening Browser
    logger.info("Opening the browser window");          
    try {
        System.setProperty(loader.getProperty(Constants.WEBDRIVER_KEY),loader.getProperty(Constants.WEBDRIVER_VALUE));  
        driver = new ChromeDriver();    
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);            
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        driver.get("www.google.com");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.println("Exception in open browser :---"+e);
    }           
}
```

'Step Definition Method' used to call 'OpenBrowser Method':

```
@Given("^User Open Browser$")
public void user_Open_Browser() throws Throwable {
    GenericAutomation.openBrowser();
}
```

Property file:

```
com.mits.webdriverKey=webdriver.chrome.driver
com.mits.webdriverValue=D:\\Chrome_Driver\\chromedriver.exe
```

Constants:

```
public static final String WEBDRIVER_KEY="com.mits.webdriverKey";
public static final String WEBDRIVER_VALUE="com.mits.webdriverValue";
```

Command lines i'm executing in Command Prompt:

```
java -cp C:\Users\mitsind314\git\IND_MITS_SeleniumProject\Cucumber_SeleniumTest\lib\*; cucumber.api.cli.Main --glue com.mits.stepDefinations C:\Users\mitsind314\git\IND_MITS_SeleniumProject\Cucumber_SeleniumTest\src\main\java\GenericAutomation.feature
```

In Eclipse, Browser is opening and rest of the code is executing as expected but in Command prompt getting below error:

> Starting in open browser:---
>   Exception in open browser:---java.lang.NullPointerException: key can't be null
>   [32m.[0m[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[32m.[0m[31mF[0m[36m-[0m[36m-[0m[36m

Comment: Can you include the full stack trace rather then just the error message? The stack trace contains all sorts of useful information and context.